# Nuxt js static pages relative URL change my link button

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am working on some static pages using Nuxt.js (MPA). Whenever I run the generate command, all  URLs start from page, i.e /customer/. For example, my structure is:

```
pages
    |customer
      |new
       - index.vue
     - index.vue
```

And in index.vue I have linked to customer/new page as:

```
<nuxt-link to="customer/new"> <b-button class="btn-sm btn-success" >nuevo</b-button></nuxt-link>
```

all works fine if I use:

```
 npm run dev
```

But if I use:

```
npm run generate
```

the link in the button link change to **/customer/customer/new** instead of **/customer/new**.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your link have to be relative to the base URL of your app, see https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router#base

So to fix your issue, declare your link with a starting slash as follows:

```
<nuxt-link to="/customer/new"> <b-button class="btn-sm btn-success" >nuevo</b-button></nuxt-link>
```

Comment: Great news, I do the change in the class and works fine in the 2 scenarios. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Perfect! Don't  forget to mark my answer as valid to close this question. have fun with nuxt ;-)